# How to change level of contours in animation for Tecplot360

Tags: plotting

I am working on a transient heat transfer problem. The problem that I have is as the time goes the range of temperature is changing but Tecplot only use one sort of levels for contour for all of time steps. Therefore the change in temperature is not very sensible at the end of the time which transient diminishes. I am wondering if there is anyway to change the levels of contours as time goes forward? (Could I specify a contour for any specific time step?)

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. This question us too specific to Tecplot, and seems to be off-topic here. Furthermore, what do you mean with "level of contours"? It's not clear in the question what you're looking for.

Comment: Sorry about being off topic. 
For the coloring of the contour tecplot uses defined levels of value and specifies each number to a color. My problem is for all of the time steps tecplot uses only one level for coloring the plot.

Comment: Have you read the manual?

Answer (score 1):

In Tecplot you can go option->color map, where you can find lot of build in color bands available. You can play a lot in "Base color map" option to get desire color contour you want.

Click a small icon next to "Contour" in "Zone surface" pallet then click levels where you can change color bands etc.

Using user defined macros you can control that but this is slightly tedious.

Last but not least you shall post your problem here: http://tecplottalk.com/forums/. You may get good answer.